# Why Google API is not returning book's Dimensions?

Tags: google-api, google-books

I did the following simple test:
1. Go to http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=books&_v=v1&_m=volumes.list&q=ISBN:9781439149034 and click the "Execute" button. 
2. Go to  http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=books&_v=v1&_m=volumes.get&volumeId=wQKyLoDT1RUC and click the "Execute" button.

On step 2 you will see the "dimensions" field while in step 1 you won't.

The difference is that step one uses book query while step two uses direct book access. I saw no documentation that indicates the two methods should work differently.

Any info on this behavior? Is it a bug or by design?